# How to accept an unsigned certificate in javascript

Tags: javascript, ssl

I am making calls to web services on SSL enabled Web Server from javascript and its provided with an unsigned certificate.

I would like to know, is there a way to accept the unsigned certificate from javascript?

Comment: The security implications of that request are alarming.

Comment: All certificates are signed, perhaps not with a signature you recognise... This has nothing to do XSS. You may be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10543894/372643).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no way.

That violates [XSS cross site calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: Actually, that has nothing to do with XSS.

Comment: It sounds like he's using JSONP, and trying to avoid the cert warning.